# Two overflow-divs should share 100% of the height

Tags: html, css

I have two "`overflow:auto`" divs and want to apply the following rules:

1. If both divs contain long `overflow (>50%)` content, the maximum height of each one should be `50%`.
2. If one has little content `(<50% height, scrollbars invisible)`, the other one can use more than `50%`, to a total of `100%`.
3. If both have little content, it would be nice, if the lower one begins at `50%` of the height. But this is not a must.

Is this possible `without JavaScript`? I don't need old browser support.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
#upper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
}
#lower {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.content {
  height: 5000px;
  background: #cccccc;
}
.short_content {
  height: 50px;
  background: #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="upper">
  <div class="short_content"></div>
</div>
<div id="lower">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope not possible just using CSS.  The far most possibility is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/divy3993/r49tyjc7/). If you want, what you want you need JS.

Comment: No Javascript = no answer lol